# AngularJS 403 error in delete request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-delete

I am sending a delete request with this code:

```
  $http({method: 'DELETE', url: '/url'}).
    success(function(status){
      //return status
    }).
    error(function(status){
    });
```

and I set `csrf` in `app.run()` as following:

```
 $http.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRFToken'] = getCookie("csrftoken");
```

GET and POST are working fine that means that the header contains a csrf token but while sending a DELETE request I am getting 403 Forbidden error and the status:

```
detail: "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."
```

Is the anything extra I need to add to the header of the DELETE request?

Comment: try adding the header directly on the request, and see if that works. If that also doesnt work, its probable your getCOokie method that fails.

Comment: You've only added CSRF to `POST` requests. Try `$http.defaults.headers.delete['X-CSRFToken']` as well

Comment: Ya that was the mistake. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply add an HTTP request interceptor to add the token to all POST / PUT / DELETE requests. For example

```
.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function() {
        return {
            request: function(config) {
                if (~['POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'].indexOf(config.method)) {
                    config.headers['X-CSRFToken'] = getCookie("csrftoken");
                }
            }
        };
    });
})
```